# Delay when populating JQuery created List Box in IE 7, 8 or 9. ASP.NET 3.5 and MVC 2.0

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, qtip2

This process entails a lot of code but lets see if I can't just give the meat of my issue.  First everything eventually works, there is just a delay in populating the ListBox when using an IE browser. No error is thrown but there is a good 5 seconds before anything happens.

Description of desired functionality: I create a modal popup using the Jquery add on qTip2.  This modal consists of 3 main controls and two buttons.  The controls are a TextBox for the user to type a word in that will populate all the objects that will populate the first ListBox.  There are two list boxes.  The first that populates all the available objects and the second populates when the user clicks on a object in the first ListBox.

Here are the two functions I call to build the modal popup.  Just done when the user clicks a LinkButton.

```
function CreateAnalyteForm(newRegulatory) {
    var AnalyteWrapperDiv = $('<div class="ta-analyteWrapper" />');
    var MessageDiv = $('<div class="ta-orderCenterDiv">Start typing the Analyte name in the          text box below to populate the first list box, then click on the Analyte name to move it over to the selected box, or click on the selected box to remove them. Once you’ve made your selections, click the Submit button to continue to the next step.</div>');
    var AnalyteTypeAheadDiv = $('<div class="ta-analyteTypeAheadDiv" />');
    var AnalyteFormDiv = $('<div class="ta-analyteSelectWrapper" />');
    var AnalyteListBox = $('<div class="ta-analyteListBox" />');
    var AnalyteSelectBox = $('<div class="ta-analyteSelectBox" />');
    var ButtonHolder = $('<div class="ta-buttonCenterDiv" />');

    var Submit = $('<a class="ta-button" onclick="javascript:AddNewAnalytes(' +  newRegulatory + ');"><span>Submit</span></a>');
    var Cancel = $('<a class="ta-button" onclick="javascript:CancelAddAnalytes();"><span>Cancel</span></a>');
    var TypeAheadInput = $('<input id="txtAnalytesTypeAhead" />');
    var ListAnalyte = $('<select id="lbAnalyteMatches" name="lbAnalyteMatches" multiple="multiple" size="10" onchange="javascript:AddAnalyte();" ></select>');
    var SelectAnalyte = $('<select id="lbSelectedAnalytes" name="lbSelectedAnalytes" multiple="multiple" size="10" onchange="javascript:RemoveAnalyte();" ></select>');

    AnalyteTypeAheadDiv.append(TypeAheadInput);              AnalyteFormDiv.append(AnalyteListBox.append(ListAnalyte)).append(AnalyteSelectBox.append(SelectAnalyte));
    ButtonHolder.append(Submit).append(Cancel);
    AnalyteWrapperDiv.append(MessageDiv).append(AnalyteTypeAheadDiv).append(AnalyteFormDiv).append(ButtonHolder);
    BuildAnalyteControl(AnalyteWrapperDiv);
}

function BuildAnalyteControl(OrderForm) {
    $('#lnkAddAnalytes').qtip({
        content: {
            title: {
                text: "Select Analytes",
                button: "Close"
            },
            text: OrderForm
    },
    position: {
        target: $('BODY'),
        my: "center center",
        at: "center center"
    },
    show: {
        ready: true,
        solo: true,
        event: "click",
        modal: true
        },
        hide: {
            event: false
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'ui-tooltip-light'
        },
        events: {
            show: function(event, api) {
                $(function() {
                    $('#txtAnalytesTypeAhead').autocomplete({
                        source: function(request, response) {
                            var data = new Array();
                            $('select[id$=lbAnalyteMatches]').empty();
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: GetULRCall() + "RegulatoryTool/GetAnalyteList",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: { analyteName: request.term },
                                success: BuildOptionSucceed
                            })
                        }
                    })
                });
            },
            hide: function(event, api) {
                $('#lnkAddAnalytes').qtip('destroy');
                $("#hdfAnalyteValues").val('');
           }
        }
    });
}

function BuildOptionSucceed(response) {
    var listItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        listItems.push('<option  value="' + response[i].Value + '">' + response[i].Text + '</option>');

    }
    $("#lbAnalyteMatches").append(listItems.join(''));
}

function AddAnalyte() {
    var analyteId = $("#hdfAnalyteValues").val();
    var analyteIds = analyteId.split(',');
    var anlyteIdDup = "1";
    $("#lbAnalyteMatches option:selected").each(function() {
        analyteId = (analyteId == "") ? this.value : analyteId + "," + this.value;
        $("#hdfAnalyteValues").val(analyteId);
        anlyteIdDup = GetUniqueId(this.value);
        $("#lbSelectedAnalytes").append('<option  value="' + this.value + '-' + anlyteIdDup + '">' + this.text + '</option>');
    });
    $('select[id$=lbAnalyteMatches] option:selected').attr('selected', false);
}
```

The createAnalyteForm is called when the user clicks a button on the page.  This creates the form than calls BuildAnalyteForm method which fires the qTip to make the modal.  As the user types in the "txtAnalytesTypeAhead" TextBox the analytes should populate the "lbAnalyteMatches" box. The analytes that get called in the AJAX are cached and are returned very quickly. This isn't the delay and the ListBox is populated quickly in FF.  Also when the user clicks an analyte in the "lbAnalyteMatches" ListBox the same kind of delay happens when populating the "lbSelectedAnalytes" ListBox.  The AddAnalyte() function is called when the user clicks on the "lbSelectedAnalytes" ListBox.